# Call function result in other function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to call my function resultin a other function. Is there any way to do that? I attached an example.

**Here is my function which I want to call it again, or reach the varaibale:**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var  tab= $(e.target).attr("href");
})
```

**In this function I want to reach the tab variable:**

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // I want to call the tab variable here
    });
```

Comment: Move the `tab` variable outside and submit function in the same scope.

Comment: Have you tried just reading the active tab when you need it?  `$('.nav .active [a[data-toggle="tab"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best solution is to remember the last tab that was triggered:

```
var lastTab = null;
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    lastTab = $(e.target).attr("href");
});

$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if(lastTab == null) {
        throw new Error("Last tab not set, how to handle this?");
    }
    else {
        // do something with the tab url in `lastTab`
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the current tab into a `data-attribute` of that form `#form`

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  var tab = $(e.target).attr("href");
  $("#form").data('current-tab', tab);
});

$("#form").submit(function(event) {
  var currentTab  = this.data('current-tab');
});
```